# Telnetlib in python not producing output?

Tags: python, telnet, telnetlib

I'm trying to use the following script:

```
import telnetlib

server = telnetlib.Telnet('mail.optonline.net', '25')
server.write('EXIT\n')
print server.read_all()
```

However, it doesn't show anything (even if I remove the server.write). By the way, this is the way to exit the telnet server, by using EXIT (then enter).

Comment: Why don't you use `smtplib`?

Answer (score 0):

SMTPLIB module from falsetru works perfectly. Thanks, falsetru!